# RSS Feed has a "\n" at the beginning. How do I remove it? - Python

Tags: python, xml, rss

I'm trying to pull data from this feed:

http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/

However it looks different from the other feeds I'm pulling from. They look like this:

https://www.ft.com/companies?format=rss

When I pull data from "https://www.ft.com/companies?format=rss" everything is pretty much straight forward as I'm using minidom to slice the data and pull everything I need like so:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.ft.com/companies?format=rss&page=1'
html = urlopen(url)
dom = minidom.parse(html)
item = dom.getElementsByTagName('item')
for node in item:
    pubdate = node.getElementsByTagName('pubDate')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    link = node.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    title = node.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

However, when I try and do the same for "http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/" with the following code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/'
html = urlopen(url)
dom = minidom.parse(html)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NAME/Desktop/Scripts/scrapesites/deleteme.py", line 6, in <module>
    dom = minidom.parse(html)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1958, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 913, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0
```

My conclusion as to why this is occurring, is because the rss structure of the two sites are slightly different. 'http://realbusiness.co.uk/feed/' has a '\n' at the first line of the page, whereas 'https://www.ft.com/companies?format=rss' doesn't.

How do I go about deleting the "\n" so I can parse the data?

If I am wrong about my solution, what would be the correct solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that is the right method to use... urlopen doesn't return a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work by reading the `\n` character before parsing like so:

```
html = urlopen(url)
html.read(1)
dom = minidom.parse(html)
```

Comment: The code is using `minidom.parse` which takes a file like object not a `string`. And yes it crashes when the file starts with a newline, space or tab.

Comment: I see it was by bad. I gravely misunderstood something. Deleted my answer and reversed the downvote. Apologies for any trouble. Cheers.